# Properties of the Shifting Theorem

Tags: laplace-transform

> The Shifting Theorem states that 
>   $$\text{If} \ \ H(t)=\begin{cases} 
>       0 & t<0 \\
>       1 & t>0 \\
>    \end{cases}, \ \ \text{then} \ \ \mathcal{L}(f(t-c)H(t-c))=e^{-cs}F(s).$$

Does this mean that
$$\mathcal{L}((-1+t)H(t-1))\equiv -\mathcal{L}((t-1)H(t-1))?$$ I'm unsure if the Heaviside function, $H(t-1)$, is affected by this change in sign.

Comment: Your last equation says $f(t)\equiv -f(t)$, where $f(t):= (t-1)H(t-1)$.

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth did my edit clear things up?

Comment: $\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}$Yes, it did. In that case though, you can note that $\L(-f(t))=-\L(f(t))$ just by *linearity of the Laplace transform* -- no need for the sifting theorem.

Comment: Yes of course. I just wasn't sure if the Heaviside function was affected. So my statement is true?

Comment: Should be all good. If in doubt, you could always write down the integral expressions for both Laplace transforms.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you wanted to do this, I would be happy to mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}$Yes, the last equation is correct, since $\L(-f(t))=-\L(f(t))$, just using linearity of the Laplace transform.